# How can I delete a user account without using Javascript?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to make a form in Rails that deletes a user without Javascript or using "method: :delete". How can I do this? When I try to use "users_destroy_path" or "user_path(@profile.user)", Rails redirects me to the "show" action of my Users controller instead of "destroy".

The form:

```
<form action="<%= user_path(@profile.user) %>"" method="delete">
      <input type="submit" value="Destroy">
</form>
```

Comment: do you have one too many `"`?

Comment: You should check whether your request reaches to server as a DELETE method? According to your situation it is being sent to server as GET.

Answer (score 0):

There is actually no `method="delete"` in an HTML form. Why the rails helpers are useful is because they create a hidden input that actually includes the DELETE request form method:

```
<input name="_method" type="hidden" value="delete">
```

You can absolutely create this yourself. Though make sure you follow the following pattern.

```
<form method="post" action="/path/to/resource">
  <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">
  <input type="submit" value="Destroy">
</form>
```

This is the same for PUT or PATCH requests. They are using the POST method on the HTML form and then declaring the PUT or PATCH in the hidden `_method` input.

```
<form method="post" action="/path/to/resource">
  <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
  --- OR ---
  <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PATCH">
  ...
```

Comment: Where did you read that? Either way, you have a few options. Using rails routes, the resource delete path is identical to the show path `?resource_name/<resource_id>`, sending the form with the `<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE">` method specified is what directs it to the proper controller. You can absolutely make custom controller routes, though there is no need. From what I can imagine... any security threats presented here can be taken care of with strong params as well as with resource policies

Answer (score 0):

you can do in this way,using destroy method in controller

```
def destroy
  @profil = Profil.find(params[:id])
  @profil.destroy
  redirect_to profil_path(@profil.user.id)
 end
```

in  user model

```
has_many :profils
```

in profile model

```
belongs_to :user
```

in view

```
<p> <%= button_to "Cancel my account", registration_path(resource_name), data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }, method: :delete %></p>
```